# How to open outside access to ElasticSearch server hosted on Windows EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I didn't find such guide or articles how to do it for ElasticSearch hosted on Windows server.

I have the EC2 amazon windows instance which running ElasticSearch server on port `9200`, but I can't achieve it by `_ec2_ip_adress:9200` outside the server.
I completely sure that all TCP ports are opened in amazon security group rules, I've turned off the firewall on the server as well.

So that is the problem in ElasticSearch configs. 
Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well but you know that then **any body** would **be able** to **delete/create** stuff in your index until you have shield.

If you really want to open it, also make sure that in windows firewall you opened port 9200.

So what i would do i would probably restrict in firewall on in Amazon access to this port for specific IPs (Actually in my project i am doing that :) )

There is one more thing to [check on which IP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) is runned as soon as i remember ES will run on private IP. Look to `network.host` default is `__local__`. Try `network.host: 0.0.0.0`

Comment: I know, but as I described I turned firewall off, so that's mean that for current moment all port should be available from outside...
In my plans I'll config cors for ES, that will solve security problem, but for current moment I can't even get access from anyware